# Why does calling `make-instance` in `let` work differently?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, let, clos

I'm exploring some possibilities of Common Lisp syntax and I wanted to make an `:around` method on `make-instance` to return some arbitrary value in some cases. For sake of simplicity, let it be `nil`, when I don't pass a needed argument. And it works, but not when calling in let:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((bar :initarg := :initform '())))

(defmethod make-instance :around ((type (eql 'foo)) &key =)
  (if (not =) nil (call-next-method)))

(print (make-instance 'foo))    ;; => NIL

(print (let ((x (make-instance 'foo))) x)) ;; => #<FOO {10037EEDF3}>
```

Can somebody explain this situation? Why is that so? Does SBCL try to be smart or is it actually a standard thing to be done? I know that I can work around it by using apply:

```
(print (let ((x (apply #'make-instance (list 'foo)))) x)) ;; => NIL
```

But I don't want to rely on this sort of workaround. Actually I can use a regular function for that and it's OK, but I want to understand why it works this way and if this behaviour can be disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like one of the optimization attempts for `MAKE-INSTANCE` and constant class names in SBCL (-> CTOR)...

This seems to work:

```
(defmethod make-instance :around ((class (eql (find-class 'foo)))
                                  &rest initargs
                                  &key =
                                  &allow-other-keys)
  (declare (ignorable initargs))
  (if (not =) nil (call-next-method)))
```

But probably useful to ask a SBCL expert or file a bug report...

Comment: Thanks, actually `(class (eql (find-class 'foo)))` is enough to make it work, but good to know those other things you used here.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is non-conforming, so any result you observe might change from one implementation to another, or from one version of an implementation to another.

See [Constraints on the COMMON-LISP Package for Conforming Programs](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abab.htm), in particular clause 19:

> Defining a method for a standardized generic function which is applicable when all of the arguments are direct instances of standardized classes.

The meta-object protocol imposes [restrictions on portable programs](http://metamodular.com/CLOS-MOP/restrictions-on-portable-programs.html):

> Any method defined by a portable program on a specified generic
>     function must have at least one specializer that is neither a
>     specified class nor an eql specializer whose associated value is an
>     instance of a specified class.

In your case, the standardized generic function is 
[`MAKE-INSTANCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_ins.htm), and the associated value of the eql specializer is `foo`, an instance of the `symbol` class.

In the `(eql (find-class 'foo))` method, the associated value is a direct instance of `standard-class`, so it is non-conforming too; you should use a custom metaclass to define new methods on `make-instance`.

Furthermore, the `:around` method returning `nil` is another problem:

> Portable programs may define methods that extend specified methods
>     unless the description of the specified method explicitly prohibits
>     this. Unless there is a specific statement to the contrary, these
>     extending methods must return whatever value was returned by the call
>     to call-next-method.

The hyperspec says that `make-instance` must return a fresh *instance* of the given *class*, where [*instance*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_i.htm#instance) is defined as either a *direct instance* or an *indirect instance*. The glossary  entry for [*direct instance*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_d.htm#direct_instance) has an example sentence that says that `make-instance` always return a *direct* instance of a class (glossary entries are normative (here this is in an example sentence, so there might be room for interpretation)). Returning NIL, however, is non-conforming.

<sup>Thanks to SBCL developers for their time; see https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/1835306</sup>